# В .NET Core 2.1 При создании таблицы в миграции, поле с типом decimal выдаёт ошибку: No type was specified for the decimal column

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

В .NET Core 2.1 При создании таблицы в миграции(code-first), поле с типом decimal

```
public decimal Income { get; set; }
```

выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> No type was specified for the decimal column 'Income' on entity type 'TableIncome'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values using 'ForHasColumnType()'.

В прошлых версиях этот код работал без проблем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ нашел [в этой статье](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/8414).

Или, если своими словами, нужно сделать эту запись следующим образом:

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
public decimal Income { get; set; }
```

Соответственно, количество знаков для decimal можем задать свои.

Вариант для Fluent API:

```
builder.Property(p => p.Income)
       .HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");
```

Ссылка на документацию: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/new-field?view=aspnetcore-2.1